# Catch click event on any part of jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a modal popup that shows up and I had to add this code for it:

```
$("#ItemDetailsPanel").click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
 hideItemDialog();
});
```

This way I was able to force its closure if clicked anywhere outside the element, but I have a datepicker inside and if I click for example to change the months the popup immediately closes. I tried with

```
$(".hasDatepicker").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

but it didn't work for me. How can I stop the executing of hideItemDialog() if the user clicks on the datepicker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker, onclick of a date , get the date and pass to URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912755/jquery-ui-datepicker-onclick-of-a-date-get-the-date-and-pass-to-url)

Comment: i would recommend a jQuery plugin like Ben Almans 'click outside' event for just this purpose rather than using any click to kill the modal http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/

Comment: My case is not the same. For me I have a problem clicking anything but the dates. If I click anywhere on the datepicker that doesn't execute select my pop up closes.

Comment: Regarding the click outside, the datepicker is placed outside of the div I am trying to close. That's the whole reason it closes my pop up.

Comment: Instead of using `document`, try with this -> http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: your jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#ui-datepicker-div').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Did the trick.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I click the prev/next buttons to advance the month it still triggers the dialog to close.