# How to get clicked cell and attach an event to it in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to get the DOM or jQuery element of the day cell when a user clicks on it in [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). My use case for this is to display a popover over the date, showing extra information.

Datepicker has the `getDate()` method, but this only returns the selected date's string representation, not the DOM element which was clicked.

I tried attaching an `.on("click")` event listener to the `.day` class, which every table day cell is tagged with. I also have an `.on("changeDate")` event listener bound to the Datepicker itself. However, I'm having some trouble with this approach.

When I try clicking on a day, the function listening to `changeDate` gets triggered every time, but the function assigned to `click` is fired only once, upon the first click. Here's a [Fiddle demonstrating this behavior](https://jsfiddle.net/f7x00o9k/2/). Any ideas?

Comment: Try using, datepicker onselect option to get instance clicked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912755/jquery-ui-datepicker-onclick-of-a-date-get-the-date-and-pass-to-url

Comment: @Ravneet, thanks, but that's a different `Datepicker`. Your link contains an answer for jQuery UI's datepicker, while I'm asking about `@eternicode`'s library.

Comment: The click event is fired only once because, each time the date is clicked, the calendar dates are reconstructed it can be noticed in the firebug. Please verify.

Comment: Yep, that looks like what's going on. I just stumbled upon that behavior while messing around with the fiddle.

Comment: I think popover can be added on changeDate event. Using, .on('changeDate', function(e) {
       // e contains the information of clicked element
    });

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and thanks to @Ravneet for the hint.

`$('#datepicker').on('changeDate')` causes the Datepicker to be re-assembled, and this removes any existing event listeners from the table cells.

Therefore, you'll need to re-attach the `click` event listener after an `.on('changeDate')` call:

```
function onChangeDate(e){
    alert('onChangeDate');
    // Must re-assign event listeners after calling ".on('changeDate')"
    $('.day').on('click', onDayClick);
}

function onDayClick(e){
    alert('onDayClick');
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  weekStart: 1,
  maxViewMode: 'years',
  format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
});

$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', onChangeDate);
$('.day').on('click', onDayClick);
```

Comment: Yes, reattach event is also right. e, in onchangeDate can also give information, please check the same too.